# Backward cpp can no longer build, missing lbdf despite linking

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, libraries, stack-trace

I am on arch and made the mistake of upgrading.

Before I could build bacward-cpp, now I get the following error:

```
../libraries/backward-cpp/backward.hpp:1357:10: error: ‘bfd_get_section_flags’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘bfd_set_section_flags’?
 1357 |     if ((bfd_get_section_flags(fobj.handle.get(), section) & SEC_ALLOC) == 0)
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |          bfd_set_section_flags
../libraries/backward-cpp/backward.hpp:1360:24: error: ‘bfd_get_section_vma’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘bfd_set_section_vma’?
 1360 |     bfd_vma sec_addr = bfd_get_section_vma(fobj.handle.get(), section);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                        bfd_set_section_vma
../libraries/backward-cpp/backward.hpp:1361:26: error: ‘bfd_get_section_size’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘bfd_set_section_size’?
 1361 |     bfd_size_type size = bfd_get_section_size(section);
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                          bfd_set_section_size
make[1]: *** [VulkanEngine.make:233: obj/Debug/VulkanDebugging.o] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:30: VulkanEngine] Error 2
```

I am linking with both `lbdf` and `ldl`, by doing `-lbfd -ldl` as arguments to g++. I am also doing `#define BACKWARD_HAS_BFD 1` before including the header as per the documentation.

I am at a loss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The corresponding macros of binutils changed slightly.

You have to drop the `_get` from the section macros and remove the `fobj.handle.get()` parameter manually: `bfd_get_section_flags(fobj.handle.get(), section)` to `bfd_section_flags(section)`.